# How to search a column to see if it contains content from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheet in a Google Sheet file - "Respondent vehicle list" and "Qualified vehicle list".

**Respondent vehicle list** 
contains a single column of vehicle names, one cell per vehicle.

1. Toyota avalon 2013
2. Ford Fusion 2015
3. 2016 Jeep Patriot
4. Mitsubishi
5. Hollander sport 2014
6. Buick regal
7. Ford Edge

**Qualified vehicle list**
contains a single column of vehicle names, one cell per vehicle.

1. Ford Edge
2. Hyundai Santa Fe
3. Hyundai Santa Fe Sport
4. Jeep Grand Cherokee
5. Kia Sorento, Mazda CX-7
6. Mitsubishi Outlander

Is there a formula in which I can scan through the Respondent vehicle list to see if any cell matches with the Qualified vehicle list? If it matches, ideally it'll mark the cell green or return "1" in the column next to it.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Did you try a mix of `importrange + vlookup` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a cell contains any of an array of values?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91339/how-to-check-if-a-cell-contains-any-of-an-array-of-values)