# Count the number of occurrences where a cell value does NOT contain a value from a pre-defined array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

I want to count the number of occurrences where a cell value does NOT contain a value from a pre-defined array.

```
Audi
BMW
Audi
Mercedes
Ford
BMW

Ford
```

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,NOT({"","Audi","BMW"}))`

So with my data the expected result would be 3. I'm using `COUNTIFS` because there will be multiple checks in my final formula.

I checked [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91339/how-to-check-if-a-cell-contains-any-of-an-array-of-values), but that returns true/false for each item, which I don't need.

Comment: What about `=COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTIFS(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` to get the rows that match your criteria, `iferror()` to weed out a possible `#N/A` error, and `counta()` to get the number of items that match said criteria, like this:

```
=counta( iferror( filter(A1:A, A1:A <> "", A1:A <> "Audi", A1:A <> "BMW") ) )
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).